# Append new element to JSON object in specific format using bash and jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I would like to append an element to an existing JSON file where I have the working directory as the key and the working directory + the contents as the value in a string array format.

Lets say I have the following structure:

```
 Docs (Directory)
 |
 +-- RandomFile.json
 |    
 +-- Readme (Working Directory)
 |  |  
 |  +-- Readme.md
 |  +-- Readyou.md
```

What I would like to achieve is the structure below with the working directory as the prefix for every element in the array.

```
"Readme": ["Readme/Readme.md", "Readme/Readyou.md"]
```

From the output above, I would like to append that to the contents of the **RandomFile.json** which currently looks like this:

```
{
  "docs": {
    "Doc": ["doc1"]
  }
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "docs": {
    "Doc": ["doc1"],
    "Readme": ["Readme/Readme.md", "Readme/Readyou.md"]
  }
}
```

Is it something that can be managed straightforward using bash and jq?

Comment: If `Readme` is the working directory, do you know that `../RandomFile.json` is the name of the file to modify, or just that there is a single JSON file in the parent directory that should be modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires `jq` 1.6 in order to use the `--args` option.

```
$ jq --arg wd "$(basename "$PWD")" '.docs+={($wd): $ARGS.positional | map("\($wd)/\(.)")}' ../RandomFile.json --args *
{
  "docs": {
    "Doc": [
      "doc1"
    ],
    "Readme": [
      "Readme/Readme.md",
      "Readme/Readyou.md"
    ]
  }
}
```

1. The shell is used to pass the base name of the current working directory as the variable `$wd`.
2. The shell is also used to pass the names of all the files in the current working directory as separate arguments.
3. The file to edit is assumed to be `../RandomFile.json`; if you only know that there is *a* JSON file in the parent, you can use `../*.json` instead.
4. Use `+=` to update the `.docs` object of the original with a new key (the working directory) and list of file names. `map` prefixes each element of `$ARGS.positional` with `$wd`.